# ES6 arrow functions not working in Workpress Gutenberg React

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am working within a Wordpress Gutenberg environment and have not been able to use arrow functions because they are assigning the function text to the const.  See the following example:

```
    const table = (table_id, tableStatus, block_table_ref) => {
        let selectedTable = getTable(table_id, tableStatus);
        if (selectedTable === undefined) {
            const newTableId = getNewTableIdByBlock(block_table_ref);
            selectedTable = getTable(newTableId, tableStatus);
    
        }
        return selectedTable;
    };
    
    console.log(table);
```

This is what gets returned to the console

```
(table_id, tableStatus, block_table_ref) => {
      let selectedTable = getTable(table_id, tableStatus);
      if (selectedTable === undefined) {
        const newTableId = getNewTableIdByBlock(block…
```

I hope someone has experience this previously and can help me identify and fix the root cause.

Comment: If you log a function, you get the function.  Seems like you might want to _call_ the function instead. `table(x, y, z)`.